# re-tagging advice

Tags: discussion, support

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347291/microsoft-bing-voice-output-api-with-laravel) about the Bing Voice Output API (and removing the [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) tag, and adding [bing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing) tag) I wondered whether the **Bing** tag is entirely appropriate or too generic.

If there were dozens of questions about this new library from Microsoft, I would just go ahead and create the new tag, and get the tag wiki info in.

But as it's only one, is it ok to leave it as [bing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bing) for now?

Comment: Do you mean, the bing voice output API only has one question?

Comment: @dsolimano: yes, so it doesn't seem worth it to create a tag just yet... but maybe I am wrong

Comment: There isn't anything better. [bing] is a small tag but still has 3 experts.  [api] is useless, [bing-api] does not apply.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks Hans, I didn't want to create the **Bing Voice Output API** tag without checking...